# Elliptic genus on torus

Tags: string-theory, path-integral, boundary-conditions, partition-function

The elliptic genus, in  defined as

$$
\mathcal{E}=\text{Tr}\,q^{L_0-\frac{c}{24}}\bar{q}^{\bar{L}_0-\frac{c}{24}}y^{\alpha J^3}
$$
can be computed as a path integral with different boundary conditions with respect the same path integral for the partition function (i.e. $\alpha=0$). I cannot see how the operator insertion $y^{\alpha J^3}$ in the partition function modifies the boundary condition of the path integral.